# Question marked duplicate with no link

Tags: bug

Normally when a question is closed as duplicate there is a link to the duplicate and the header looks like this:
[image]

But I noticed [this question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/76329/why-does-one-have-to-use-%E3%81%AA%E3%81%8C%E3%82%89-instead-of-%E3%81%A4%E3%81%A4-in-this-sentence) today that seems to have been closed as a duplicate but there is no link:
[image]

Strangely though, there is still a link in the 'Linked' questions part in the right hand column:
[image]

even though this link doesn't appear in any question, answer or comment.

What is going on here? Is this a weird anomaly, a new way of doing things, or something that's always existed that I don't know about?

Comment: Even weirder: the [edit link](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/originals/76329/edit) to change which questions it's linked to 404s!  Re-tagging as bug.

Comment: Another example https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/76353/1628 seems to happen when the asker accepts a duplicate vote...?